# Meteor (js framework) : How can I call a function on the server from an event on the browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, meteor

I'm just starting to learn Meteor. I want to have a button on the client that fires off a serverside function. How should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a method at the server using Meteor.methods, then on the client use Meteor.call.

http://docs.meteor.com/0.6.0/#meteor_methods

http://docs.meteor.com/0.6.0/#meteor_call

Answer (score 5):

That's quite simple, here is a sample of code :

```
// On server side :
Meteor.methods({
   myMethodName: function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
      // doWhatYouWantHere;
   }
});

// On client side :
Template.YourTplWhereIsPLacedTHeButton.events({
   'click #cssSelectorToYourButton': function () {
      var myArg1 = 1, myArg2 = 2, myArg3 = 3;
      Meteor.call('myMethodName', myArg1, myArg2, myArg3/*, function() {} */);
   }
});
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: How would you hand in arguments to a function like that? Couldn't see it in the docs linked in the other answer.